# Django Rest Framework pre-populate form with specific queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Basically in a popup (bootstrap) I would like to have all specified pre-populated fields from my model.

I found this code (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-rest-framework/HTMLFormRenderer/django-rest-framework/s24WFvnWMxw/hhmaD6Qw0AMJ)

```
class CreatePerformanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Performance
    fields = ('field1', 'field2')

class PerformanceCreateView(ListCreateAPIView): 
    serializer_class = PerformanceCreateSerializer
    model = Performance
    template_name = 'core/perform.html'

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        data = {'
            form': CreatePerformanceForm()
        }
        return Response(data)
```

My question is the same.
Is there a way to create the form directly from the serializer so I don't have to create a Django form?

I looked at HTMLFormRenderer, but the DRF doc is quiet poor about this issue.

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 2):

See [this issue](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/310). Important part:

> There are some improvements that could be made there [to HTMLFormRenderer], notably supporting error messaging against fields, and rendering the serializer directly into html without creating a Django form in order to do so [...]

So basically, HTMLFormRenderer also uses Django forms. Also, you are right, the documentation doesn't provide too much support for it. Even more, it seems that this renderer might soon change. See [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers#htmlformrenderer). Quote:

> Note that the template used by the HTMLFormRenderer class, and the context submitted to it may be subject to change. If you need to use this renderer class it is advised that you either make a local copy of the class and templates, or follow the release note on REST framework upgrades closely.

I know this doesn't help much, but for now there is no better way than the way you did it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I read the doc too, hence I suppose it's the only solution.